# My Kubuntu desktop has vanished- no icons, launchers, left-click

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I'm not sure what I did, but now my KDE desktop is just a blank screen.  I am still able to log onto a gnome session, and the guest account has a perfeclty fine Kubuntu session, but no matter what I do I can't get a Kubuntu session with my own login.

Comment: Try reinstalling kubuntu-desktop

Comment: I did that, and the new installation looks great in the guest account, but in mine the most I can get is the outline of a window if I run ccsm from the terminal.

Comment: It will not let me comment. Same problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/625044/plasma-has-vanished-kubuntu-15-04

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347919

Somehow ??? permissions had changed, in .cache a file  .cache/.ksycoca5 was owned by root

The following command worked from the terminal:

```
sudo chown yourusername:yourusername ~/.cache/ksycoca5
```

it all came back.

In the interim I installed gnome.